# Access outer class's methods after extending inner class

Tags: java, class, extend

I know I can access methods of outer class from within the inner class.
Like the below class:

```
class outer {

    void outerMethod() {}

    class inner {

        void innerMethod() {
            outerMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how can I do this if I extended the inner class?

I want to do the following:

```
class newClass extends outer.inner {

    void innerMethod() {
        outerMethod();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access `method()` from `newClass`

Comment: sorry, I corrected it now

Comment: Do you want `newClass` to be enclosed in the class `outer`, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance of non-static `inner` class requires existence of `outer` class instance which it will belong to.
So to make `class newClass extends outer.inner {` compile you either need to

1. make `inner` class static, and remove requirement of existence of `outer` class instance (but this will also limit your class a little)
2. or ensure that `inner` will belong to some `outer` instance, which you can do by calling `outerInstance.super()` inside your constructor of your class which extends this inner class.

In case of option 2, probably simplest solution would be explicitly passing instance of `outer` to your class like

```
class newClass extends outer.inner {

    private outer o;

    public newClass(outer outerInstance) {
        outerInstance.super();
        this.o = outerInstance;
    }

    void innerMethod() {
        o.outerMethod();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call your `outerMethod()` on passed instance of `outer` class.

But remember that calling `outerMethod` is possible only when this method has proper visibility for your `newClass`. So despite the fact that `inner` is able to use any method of its outer class your `newClass` may not have access to it.

Comment: I thought that all properties and privileges are passed through inheritence, but appearently it's not the case for inner class inheritence.

Comment: No, privileges are not inherited, that is why extending inner class is rarely good decision.